# 18.04 to 20.04 Upgrade Text Is Now Just Boxes

Tags: upgrade, gui

I received a pop up while doing my thing in 18.04 asking if I wanted to upgrade my OS to 20.04. Why yes, thanks. So I followed the prompts, rebooted, and immediately noticed all text characters in the OS are now boxes. I did some looking around the web and saw others having the same or similar issue. I have re-installed my nVidia driver. No luck. I can go into Tweaks and see different fonts but I can't select them/apply them.

Thanks very much for any direction. I am a noob level user and not having actual words will likely make the fix more challenging.

Comment: Open a terminal and type `ls /usr/bin/*session` then **edit** your question above and let us know the result please.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I resolved my issue. For me it was simply going into Tweaks and selecting a font. A little difficult because the icon changed with the upgrade and no text but eventually got it sorted out. Maybe this solution can aid someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Tweaks>Fonts>Interface Text select anything to change boxes to characters.